Bikepacking in Morocco
I'm planning my (super)next cycle tour next summer which will take me to Morocco, among other places.
However, I find contrary information regarding cycle tours in Morocco. There are travel reports that advertise cycle tours and on the other hand there is e.g. the recommendation of the German government to avoid rural areas in Morocco (not verbatim).
I have several questions:
Where can I find out which region I should avoid and which not?
Are there any very important tips, e.g. only sleep on a campsite etc...?

Thank you i wasnt shure which Page i should poste it

@Weiss fair enough - there's elements of both but the bulk of the question is specific to Morocco.  Migrating to Travel.SE now.   And it sounds like a great trip, enjoy!

Thank you so much!

Someone in my (long-distance) club went there last year.  I haven't spoken to him since, but he's posted some stuff online. For example: https://medium.com/@rgoesfar/gt-10-my-past-and-present-cycling-worlds-collide-26b98d641607

@ChrisH-UK love that

The French foreign ministry gives the following advice:
Mostly harmless, but avoid going alone in remote areas and be extra vigilant when driving.
French link, but I would be surprised if there weren't a German equivalent
You'll find a map you should be able to understand even without speaking one word of French near the bottom of the page. I'm explicitly not copying this map here as it can change over time.
Additional warning is given specifically regarding the Rif/ⴰⵔⵔⵉⴼ area, warning not to stop during the day (by car is assumed, so it basically would be a 'no-go' for bikes (and even motorbikes might be a bad idea)).
Also an additional warning is given regarding single women.
TL;DR: Don't do this alone, and avoid the south of the country.

Reading the English translation of the linked page under "Transport risks" makes me think that traveling by bike is a generally bad idea - "Traffic there is a danger, due to frequent traffic offences, the presence of unattended animals, or unforeseeable and untimely behaviour on the part of public transport drivers (large taxis, coaches, lorries)." "The tracks that connect the main roads are poorly maintained" - Main roads are suicidal on a bike and side roads are at risk of theft, etc.

I didn't want to make a generalization of your last phrase, as I never went there. But that's my feeling too.

Western Sahara ('Sahara Occidental' on the French map) is, at best, a 'disputed territory'. Some call it 'occupied'. So, best avoided unless there is a very good reason to go there. There was also the horrific 2018 double murder of two young Scandinavian women backpackers camping alone in the High Atlas mountains (not in the far south, closer to Marrakesh), which no doubt accounts for some of the warnings. Obviously many millions visit Morocco every year with nothing more serious happening to them than being overcharged here and there.
